# Query to join two tables and to use LISTAGG function

Tags: oracle, listagg

I have two tables

```
price
--------

id      value   key
sku1    r1      12  
sku1    r2      13  
sku2    r1      12
sku3    r1      14

specialprice
-----

id      value   key startdate   enddate
sku2    r2      13  20-Mar      20-May
sku3    r1      15  20-Mar      20-May
```

I am trying to use LISTAGG function and bring output like:

```
output
------
skuid   value
sku1    r1:12,r2:13
sku2    r2:13
sku3    r1:15
```

If there is an entry in specialprice table and sysdate is between startdate and enddate then i need to consider that otherwise i need to get value from price table.
In price table a id may have two entries i need to LISTAGG those two records.
specialprice table may not have entry for the id in price table. So i am using FULL OUTER JOIN

PFB Query which i constructed:

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  listagg (a.value | | ':' | | nvl (a.key, ' '), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.value) AS price
FROM price a 
FULL OUTER JOIN specialprice b
  ON(b.id = a.id)
WHERE sysdate between b.startdate and b.enddate
GROUP BY a.id
```

but issue is i am not able to get the specialprice table value and key joined.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.id,listagg (a.value | | ':' | | nvl (a.key, ' '), ',') 
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.value) AS price 
  FROM price a 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN specialprice b 
  ON(b.id = a.id and a.value = b.value and a.key = b.key) 
  WHERE (sysdate between b.startdate and b.enddate OR b.id IS NULL) 
  GROUP BY a.id
```

Based on the requirement explained, if there is a matching id in b it must be current record. If not matching record is found, still a's data must be used. A LEFT OUTER JOIN should be sufficient. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select id, listagg(value) within group(order by value) as price
from (
select
  p.id, 
  case when sp.id is not null and sysdate between sp.startdate and sp.enddate
    then p.value||':'||p.key
    else p.value||':'||p.key
  end as value
from price p
left outer join specialprice sp
  on p.id = sp.id
)
group by id;
```